# Include stylesheet in multiple manifest files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets

There are two manifest files, each one has a require directive:

```
*= require 'normalize'
```

`normalize` is imported only in one manifest file. How can a stylesheet be shared between two manifest files?

Comment: The manifests are loaded on **different** pages, right (meaning, they're not loaded together on the same page)?

Comment: @PaulRichter Yes. Each layout has its own manifest.

Comment: Hmm you're doing it right so far as I can tell. Are the manifests in different directories? If so you'll need to properly indicate the path (relative is fine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`normalize` wasn't included because of `stub` directive in one manifest file. `new` manifest was stubbed in `application`. `stub` directive excluded `new` manifest and all css that was required there too, that's why some css files weren't imported.